# get Generic Class from GetType

Tags: vb.net, generics, gettype

I tried to get data from database by using GetType.

Example in VB.net:

```
Dim genericObject = Me.UnitOfWork.GetAll(Of GetType("MyNamespace.Student"))()
```

For sure this code got error. But i don't have any idea to retrieve data from database by using string of class name.

My project is, i tried to create dynamic document merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `Me.UnitOfWork.GetAll(of MyNamespace.Student)()`. If the class isn't known at compile time then you'll need to invoke it via reflection

```
Dim method As MethodInfo = Me.UnitOfWork.GetType().GetMethod("GetAll")
Dim generic As MethodInfo = method.MakeGenericMethod(GetType("MyNamespace.Student"))
generic.Invoke(Me.UnitOfWork, Nothing)
```

See this answer for more details:
[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: I'm presuming you mean `method` is null. Check that the GetAll method exists on UnitOfWork and that it's a public instance method. Without more knowledge of what GetAll is I can't help further

Comment: Its work!  Thank so much @FloatingKiwi.
GetAll will return IQueryable. 

I just use this function
`Type.GetType("MyNamespace.Student, MyNamespace")`

Do you know how to call where function?
Actually what i want to do

`Me.unitofwork.GetAll(Of MyNamespace.Student).where(function(x) x.Id = 1)`

Comment: Me.unitofwork.GetAll(Of MyNamespace.Student).where(function(x) x.Id = 1).FirstorDefault